# Actual and formal arguments differ in length

Tags: java

I have got the following code `Simmulation.java`, but when I tried compiling it, it is coming up with an error saying,

`error: constructor CashewPallet in class CashewPallet cannot be applied to give types;`

`CashewPallet c1 = new CashewPallet();`

`Required: String,int, found: no arguments`

`Reason: Actual and formal arguments differ in length`

I know what this error means, and when I tried to fix the line to `CashewPallet c1 = new CashewPallet(String, int);` and again `CashewPallet c1 = new CashewPallet(nutType, id);` but either didn't work! AND now I am not sure how can this be solved. 
I am new to this, any help is much appreciated.
Many Thanks in advance!
Please bear with me.

**EDIT :** Thank you for the answers everyone! It has worked now and compiled successfully BUT when I executed it, it is coming up with `error: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException :0 at Simmulation.main(Simmulation.java:201)` Any help in fixing it Please?

THANK YOU!

This is Simmulation.java file

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;


public class Simmulation implements Operation {

Queue<CashewPallet> inputQueue=new LinkedList<CashewPallet>();
Stack<CashewPallet> stBay1=new Stack<CashewPallet>();
Stack<CashewPallet> stBay2=new Stack<CashewPallet>();
FileOutputStream fout4;
PrintWriter pw;
static int tick=0;

CashewPallet c1;
String temp;
Scanner sc;

public Simmulation(String fn) 
{
    int index=0;
    String nutType="";
    int id=0;

    Scanner s2 ;

    try
    {
        sc = new Scanner(new File(fn));
        fout4=new FileOutputStream("nuts.txt");
        pw=new PrintWriter(fout4,true);
        String eol = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while(sc.hasNextLine())
        {
            tick++;
            s2 = new Scanner(sc.nextLine());
            if(s2.hasNext())
            {
                while ( s2.hasNext())
                {
                    String s = s2.next();
                    if(index==0)
                    {
                        nutType=s;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        id=Integer.parseInt(s);
                    } 
                    index++;
                }
                System.out.println("Nuttype "+nutType+" Id is "+id+"tick "+tick);
                if((nutType.equalsIgnoreCase("A")||nutType.equalsIgnoreCase("P")|| nutType.equalsIgnoreCase("C")|| nutType.equalsIgnoreCase("W")) && id!=0)
                inputQueue.add(new CashewPallet(nutType.toUpperCase(),id));
                System.out.println("Size of Queue "+inputQueue.size());
                int k=0;
                if(!inputQueue.isEmpty())
                {
                    while(inputQueue.size()>k)
                    {
                        // stBay1.push(inputQueue.poll());
                        process(inputQueue.poll());
                        k++;
                    }
                    // System.out.println("Size of input "+inputQueue.size() +" Size of stay "+stBay1.size());      

                }
            }    
            else
            {
                fout4.write(" ".getBytes());
            }
            index=0;   
            if(!stBay2.isEmpty())
            {
                while(!stBay2.isEmpty())
                {
                    c1=stBay2.pop();
                    temp=tick+" "+c1.getNutType()+" "+c1.getId()+eol;
                    fout4.write(temp.getBytes());
                }
                // System.out.println("Nut final "+ stBay2.peek().getNutType());
            }
             else
             {
                 temp=tick+eol;
                 fout4.write(temp.getBytes());
             }
         }
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
         System.out.println("Exception "+e);
     }
     closeStream();
 }


public CashewPallet process( CashewPallet c)
{      
    //CashewPallet  c=new CashewPallet();
    int k=0;
    //while(stBay.size()>k)
    //{
    //c=stBay.pop();
    String operation=c.getNutType();

    if(c.getPriority()==1)
    {
         shelling(c);
             washing(c);
                     packing(c);
                     //stBay2.push(c);
    }
    else
    {
        switch(operation)
        {
            case "A": shelling(c);
                       washing(c);
                       packing(c);
            break;

            case "C": washing(c);
                      packing(c);
            break;

            case "W" : washing(c);
                      shelling(c);
                       packing(c);
            break;               

        }
    }
    return c;
}
public void closeStream()
{
    try
    {
        fout4.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
}

public boolean shelling(CashewPallet c)
{
    // for(int i=0;i<20; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Performing Shelling for  "+c.getNutType());
    }
    return true;
}
public boolean washing(CashewPallet c)
{
   // for(int i=0;i<20; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Performing Washing for  "+c.getNutType());
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean packing(CashewPallet c)
{
    //for(int i=0;i<20; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Performing Packing for  "+c.getNutType());
    }
    stBay2.push(c);
    return true;
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    new Simmulation(args[0]);
}
```

This is CashewPallet.java file

```
public class CashewPallet {
private String nutType;
private int id;
private int priority;
private int opTick;

public int getOpTick() {
    return opTick;
}

public void setOpTick(int opTick) {
    this.opTick = opTick;
}
public int getPriority() {
    return priority;
}

public void setPriority(int priority) {
    this.priority = priority;
}

public CashewPallet(String nutType, int id) {
    this.nutType = nutType;
    this.id = id;

    if(this.nutType.equalsIgnoreCase("p"))
    {
        priority=1;
    }
    else
    {
        priority=0;
    }
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNutType() {
    return nutType;
}

public void setNutType(String nutType) {
    this.nutType = nutType;
}
```

Comment: Is all that code necessary? The error has to do with how you are invoking a constructor.

Comment: Why is `c1` declared as a member of `Simulation`? from the code shown you can leave it a  local variable.

Comment: @Vandale Thank you it actually worked! and made life easier!

Comment: Re: Edit.  1) You forgot to pass an argument to your program.  2) If you had failed to decipher the error message (unlikely, since it is very clear), then a new question is the correct way to go.  3) You don't need to ask a new question, you should be able to figure out the answer from the error message and/or google.

Comment: @Paul Hicks Yes the compiling error has been fixed! but now I am having problem with execution. I have mentioned it in EDIT!

Comment: Asking a new question should not be done as an edit to an existing question.  But more importantly, this is a very easy-to-answer question so have a go at answering it on your own.  Personal research is a highly-valued skill here on stackoverflow.  (Hint: I answered it as point 1 in my previous comment)

Answer (score 1):

When you use `CashewPallet`'s constructor, you need to supply **actual values** for the arguments. The arguments are `String nutType` and `int id`, which means you need to supply a `String` that will go into `nutType` and an `int` that will go into `id`. For example:

```
CashewPallet c1 = new CashewPallet("Pecan", 42);
```

Comment: Which also means that the location of the construction is wrong - it shouldn't be done at declaration time - it should be done somewhere in the code where the nut type and id becomes known.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Please refer to the question again, I have edited with some more information.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor in `CashewPallet` requires a `String` and an `int`; you didn't provide them:

```
public CashewPallet(String nutType, int id)
```

You called it like this:

```
CashewPallet c1 = new CashewPallet();
```

Change it to something like:

```
CashewPallet c1 = new CashewPallet("Peanut",1337);
```

---

EDIT:

You're getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` on this line:

```
new Simmulation(args[0]);
```

That's in your `args[0]`. If that's out of bounds, then that means that you don't have command line arguments.

You should call it with command line arguments (or specifically one command line argument).

```
java Simmulation myarg
```

In this case your argument is the name of your file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Please refer to the question again, I have edited with some more information.

Comment: @user3615120 Does that answer your question?

Comment: Sort of! So what should I be doing to fix it now?

Comment: @user3615120 You need to have an argument. Edited.

Comment: It is not working and coming up with compiling error `; expected` ?

Comment: @user3615120 Also if this answer is helping you you should consider accepting it.

Comment: Yes definitely I will! but I need to get this error fixed before that. Sorry! AND the errors are at 1) java Simmulation myarg ( `; expected` ) and 2) `not a statement`